# Check in range precondition

Tags: java, guava, preconditions

I like guava preconditions, but what I really need from it is one more method - check that the number is in range. Smt like this

```
//probably there should be checkStateInRange also
public static void checkArgumentInRange(double value, int min, int max) {
    if (value < min || value > max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s must be in range [%s, %s]", value, min, max));
    }
}
```

I believe I'm not alone and it's a pretty common case. But such method doesn't exist. Is there any reasons to not put such methods in `com.google.common.base.Preconditions`?

Comment: P.S. Yes, I know that I can create new classes like Angle to put some restriction on values.

Comment: For one you would need 4 such methods to cover inclusive and exclusive boundary conditions.

Comment: @rsp, correct. Actually, it's not so bad. Alternatively, we can introduce `Range` class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite a few reasons I'd say. Here are the main ones:

- There's no standard Java exception type for "value out of range". Note that each of the `Preconditions` methods throws a specific exception type for what it checks: `NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. A generalized range check would have no exception more specific than `IllegalArgumentException` to throw.
- `checkArgument` and `checkState` do everything you need. You can just write `checkArgument(value >= min && value <= max, ...)`. It's simple and obvious what you're checking.

Additionally:

- There are too many different combinations you might want here. Exclusive/inclusive bounds as @rsp mentions, etc.
- It's limiting to only allow `int`s for the bounds, so you would really like to allow any `Comparable` there.
- At this point you notice you're just checking if the value is contained in a [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html).

Comment: `Range` class with `contains` method is a really good point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can get very close by using `checkArgument()`:

```
checkArgument(min < value && value < max, "%s must be in range [%s, %s]", value, min, max);
```

which, if you add the message strings to your own constant definitions, isn't much boilerplate and has all the flexibility you need.

Comment: [ and ] is closed range.
So, the condition "min < value && value < max" should represent to "(%s, %s)".

ref. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained